# Entity Framework throws exception on updates only - Invalid object name 'dbo.BirdBrain.service'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

I've created an EF Core model from an existing database and all operations on entities work EXCEPT for updates; on updates EF Core is using an incorrect database name.

eg. When I perform an update I get a `SqlException: Invalid object name 'BirdBrain.dbo.services'.`. `BirdBrainContext` is the name of my DbContext, but the database I'm connecting to is `BirdBrain_test`.

I tried updating from EF Core 2.1 to EF Core 2.2 but the issue persists. When connecting to the production database named `BirdBrain` the same code functions perfectly.

I am initializing my context using a connection string like the following

```
Server=****;Database=BirdBrain_test;User Id=****;Password=****;Trusted_Connection=False;Multisubnetfailover=true;
```

and I do not know how this leads to updates being run against `'BirdBrain.dbo.services'` when the database is `BirdBrain_test`.

Relevant DbContext code

```cs
public class BirdBrainContextFactory
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public BirdBrainContextFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public BirdBrainContext Create()
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BirdBrainContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
        return new BirdBrainContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}

public class BirdBrainContext : DbContext
{
    public BirdBrainContext(DbContextOptions<BirdBrainContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Service>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Tag)
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedAt)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getutcdate())");

            entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedAt)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getutcdate())");
        });
    }
}
```

The table for the associated I am using the TableAttribute to refer to the table name.

```cs
[Table("services")]
public class Service
{
  ...
}
```

Relevant Update code

```cs
public Service UpdateService(Service service)
{
    using (var context = _contextFactory.Create())
    {
        EnforceServiceExists(context, service);
        context.Entry(service).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
        return service;
    }
}
```

Gets, Inserts, and Deletes work on this same table.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at DataService.BirdBrainContext.SaveChanges() in C:\git\BirdBrainAPI\src\DataService\BirdBrainContext.cs:line 180
...

Inner Exception 1:
SqlException: Invalid object name 'BirdBrain.dbo.services'.
```

EDIT: I added EF Core logging as Ivan Stoev suggested and pasted the results for the update below. It looks like EF is connecting to the `BirdBrain_test` database and running a `UPDATE [services] ...` as opposed to `UPDATE [BirdBrain].[dbo].[services]` as the error would suggest. Still not sure what is going on.

```
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20001]
      Opened connection to database 'BirdBrain_test' on server '****'.
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction[20200]
      Beginning transaction with isolation level 'ReadCommitted'.
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@p19='?' (DbType = Int32), @p0='?' (DbType = DateTime), ...], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      UPDATE [services] SET [created_at] = @p0, ... , [updated_at] = @p18
      WHERE [id] = @p19;
      SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (61ms) [Parameters=[@p19='?' (DbType = Int32), @p0='?' (DbType = DateTime), ...], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      UPDATE [services] SET [created_at] = @p0, ... , [updated_at] = @p18
      WHERE [id] = @p19;
      SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'BirdBrain.dbo.services'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
ClientConnectionId:b2b87fd1-8e34-4fcf-80f1-290de30b28dd
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
```

Comment: Are you using an SPs that have been coded using 3 part naming?

Comment: Yeah, where is `BirdBrain.dbo.` coming from? Normally EF Core 2.2. does not add schema prefix to table names. Is there some data annotation or fluent configuration not shown in the post?

Comment: @Larnu I am not using any stored procedures

Comment: @IvanStoev I have no annotations or configurations present outside of what I have posted and I can't find the string `dbo` anywhere in my project. I'm really perplexed as to why only Updates are impacted

Comment: That's strange of course. Might be from db trigger (`instead of update`?) or something. Turn on the EF Core [Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) and see what SQL command EF Core is trying to execute.

Comment: @IvanStoev please see edit

Comment: if you are sure that you only have one connectionString, then it's probably hardcoded somewhere in your code. I would suggest to debug with F11 to follow the code line by line, this will help you fix it.

Comment: It proves that the problem is not in EF Core. Since you are using existing database, you have to check the database. For instance, using VS SqlServer Object Explorer, connect to the database, expand Tables - dbo.services and then either View Code or View Designer and seek for `BirdBrain` inside. Or contact the database designer/administrator. Who knows, `services` might not even be a table, but view, or might have triggers replacing insert, update, delete with update trigger having a bug. There is nothing more you can do at EF Core side.

Comment: Check the user account for its default database

Comment: @IvanStoev You are absolutely correct. There was an update trigger on the `services` table that was using the three part naming. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can credit you with the solution?

Comment: Hey, glad it helped! I believe it will be more appropriate if you post a short self answer what was the case and how you resolved it (because mine were just wild guesses). Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that there was an underlying update trigger on the database that was using the `BirdBrain.dbo.services` naming. I tested changing naming to `services` from `BirdBrain.dbo.services` and this resolved the error. Ultimately I removed the trigger entirely as the logic it handled was unnecessary at the present date.

To figure this out I added [logging to the DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) as @IvanStoev suggested and confirmed that that EF was in fact targetting the `services` object correctly and *not* `BirdBrain.dbo.services` as I originally believed.

I then connected to the database using SSMS and expanded the table to look at its triggers, which was where I found the offending trigger.

In case you are facing a similar issue, you should check if there are any triggers on the table you are modifying.